# Where am I making my mistake? (intervals of convergence)

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

The sum is:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x-6)^n}{(-8)^nn}
\end{align}
I end up with $|(x - 6)/8| < 1$ and therefore, $-8 < 6 - x < 8$ so $14 > x > -2$, but that gives me the wrong answer. 
 
I've been up all night doing this homework so chances are I'm missing something obvious or committing a rookie mistake. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I changed the sum to latex, please check if it is still correct. And maybe start to formulate the question.

Comment: @macydanim THank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have derived $-8<6-x<8$. Subtracting $6$ from each term gives $-14<-x<2$. Now negating all the terms gives $-2<x<14$.

So now we check if the sum converges at the boundary points of the interval. When $x = 14$, the sum is $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, which converges. When $x = -2$, the sum is $\sum \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges. The sum should then converge on $-2<x\leq 14$.

Comment: yes, sorry, that was a mistake. I meant to write -2.

Comment: My homework website must've been acting up (it'll do this sometimes) so it must've not been accepting the correct answer. I just typed in -2 & 14 and it worked. Thank you for answering froggie.